# Equivalent condition of the following group presentation to give a group of order $mn$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group (not necessary abelian) generated by $a, b$ that has a group presentation: $$\langle a, b \mid a^m = 1, b^n = 1, ba = a^rb\rangle. $$
I have to prove that $G$ is of order $mn$ if and only if  $r^n = 1 \pmod{m}$. I was able to prove the $\leftarrow$ side, but I'm stuck in proving the $\rightarrow$ side.

Comment: Use `\pmod{m}` to produce the spacing, parentheses, and "mod" text in roman typeface. `\mod` produces the wrong spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $b^n = 1$ and $bab^{-1} = a^r$ it follows, that $a = b^{n}ab^{-n} = a^{r^n}$, which means $a^{r^n - 1} = 1$.

Because we also have $a^m = 1$ we can conclude that $a^{GCD(m, r^n - 1)} = 1$. And because it is not hard to see, that $a \mapsto a^r$ is an automorphism of $\langle a \rangle_{GCD(m, r^n - 1)}$ we can see that

$$\langle a, b | a^m = 1, b^n = 1, bab^{-1} = a^r\rangle \cong \langle a \rangle_{GCD(m, r^n - 1)} \rtimes_{a \mapsto a^r} \langle b \rangle_{n}$$

which is a group of order $nGCD(m, r^n - 1)$